# Junit 5 : AssertionFailedError: expected: <true> but was: <false>

Tags: exception, junit, assert, junit5

I'm trying to write a unit test case for the below function in the service class

```
@Service
    public class currencyHandler {
        public boolean isNoDecimal(String currency) {
            return "JPY".equalsIgnoreCase(currency) || "KRW".equalsIgnoreCase(currency);
        }
    }
```

Below is the unit case:

```
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
    import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
    import org.svc.it.handlers;
    
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    public class CurrencyTests {
    
        @Mock
        CurrencyHandler currencyHandlerTest;
    
        @Test
        public void isNoCurrency() throws Exception {
            assertTrue(currencyHandlerTest.isNoCurrency("ABC"));
            assertTrue(currencyHandlerTest.isNoCurrency("XYZ"));
            assertFalse(currencyHandlerTest.isNoCurrency("BOGUS"));
            assertFalse(currencyHandlerTest.isNoCurrency(""));
            assertFalse(currencyHandlerTest.isNoCurrency(null));
        }
    }
```

Below is the error when I run above unit test case:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <true> but was: <false>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue(Assertions.java:162)
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong with @Mock object.
Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write a unit test for the `CurrencyHandler` class, you must test against an instance of that class. You must not test against an instance of a **mock** of that class.

The following shows how to write such a unit test.

```
package example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

class CurrencyHandlerTests {

    private CurrencyHandler currencyHandler = new CurrencyHandler();

    @Test
    void isNoDecimal() {
        assertTrue(currencyHandler.isNoDecimal("JPY"));
        assertTrue(currencyHandler.isNoDecimal("KRW"));
        assertFalse(currencyHandler.isNoDecimal("BOGUS"));
        assertFalse(currencyHandler.isNoDecimal(""));
        assertFalse(currencyHandler.isNoDecimal(null));
    }
}
```

To better understand the concepts here, I recommend that you read some articles or books on unit testing, mocks, and the SUT (subject under test).

In addition, you do not need to register the `SpringExtension` if you are writing a pure unit test like the one above, since a pure unit test does not need to interact with components in a Spring `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm still getting the same. I have edited the question to provide additional information.

Comment: I revised my answer to explain that you do not need a mock for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your time and all the help!